# .htaccess 404 redirect not working

Tags: html, .htaccess

So I have this code:

```
# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working

RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
```

and I have the file 404.php in the folder errors but it's not working.

Comment: is that all that's in your htaccess file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correctly formatted and should work. The only thing I would suggest is that you should ensure your .htaccess file is **one directory up** from the */errors* folder and also ensure your 404.php is properly formatted.